# if statement not functioning properly

Tags: java

Hi stackers,

```
      System.out.print("Enter your first name:  ");
  firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
  if(firstName!="Mike"&&firstName!="mike"&&firstName!="Diane"&&firstName!="diane")
  {
      System.out.println("derp");
  }
  else
      discount=true;
```

however, this is the result:

```
Enter your first name:  diane
derp
```

if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great thank you very much!

Comment: I tried messing with the conditions of the statement to no avail

Comment: Your if condition needs `||` not `&&`.

Comment: Also, for your specific case - `!firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("mike") && !firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("diane")`

Comment: You need to use the `.equals()` method. == and != check the instance, not the content of the String.

Comment: Use the String.equals(String other) function to compare strings, not the == operator.

Comment: @PeterJi answer posted for your acceptance

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter your first name:  ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (!(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("mike") || (firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("diane")))) {
            System.out.println("derp");
        } else
            System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter your first name:  diane
true
```